# Equivalence class of parametrized surfaces which induce the same current

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $n \geq 2$. A $k$-current is a linear functional on compactly supported smooth forms on $M$, denoted $T: \Omega^k_c(M) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Let $X: [0,1]^2 \to M$ be a piecewise smooth parametrized surface. This induces a $2$-current $T_X$ on $M$ via integration:
$$
T_X(\omega) = \int_X \omega.
$$

However, two different parametrized surfaces can induce the same current. One example is by reparametrizing the surface, and another example is by "folding." For instance, consider $Y: [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$
Y(s,t) = \begin{cases}
(s,t) & : s\in [0,1/2] \\
(1 - s, t) & : s \in (1/2, 1].
\end{cases}
$$
The induced current $T_Y = 0$ is trivial, which is the same as the current induced by the constant surface.

**Question:** Is there a known characterization of the equivalence class of parametrized surfaces which induce the same current? If so, is there a reference on this?

Thank you!